# I am working on grep and zgrep ing a file

Tags: regex, perl, grep

I am new to regex and Perl. Can you please help if this is a right syntax in Perl when porting from csh:

**csh:**

```
set shipDate = `zgrep "::RUNTIME:: SHIP end time/date:" $shipLogFile | sed 's/.*time\/date\://g' | sed 's#"##g'`
```

**Perl:**

```
  my $wardSwizzled     = "$WARD/ship/ip/${DBB1}/swizzled";
  my $wardpds          = "$wardSwizzled/pds/logs/${DBB1}";
  my $accept10SumFile  = "$wardpds.ccdo_accept10.iss.log.sum";
  my $wardReview       = "$wardSwizzled/review/${DBB1}";
  my $reviewCloseFile  = "$wardReview.close";
  my $wardship         = "$WARD/ship/log/${DBB1}";    
  my $shipLogFile      = "$wardship.ship.log";

  my @shipDate;
  open my $fh, '<', $shipLogFile or die "Can't open $shipLogFile: $!";
  while (<$fh>)
  {
  next if (!m/::RUNTIME:: SHIP end time/date:/);
  push @shipDate, $.;
  }
  close $fh;
```

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: Please add a couple of lines of lines in `shipLogFile` look like in the original question.

Comment: I am not sure if this line is right ""next if (!m/::RUNTIME:: SHIP end time/date:/);"" because I see in my texteditor "date:/ " showing in a different color. So I am guessing the syntax is wrong.

Comment: @shawn - ok I added it to my question. The lines of shipLogFile

Comment: Thanks, but I want to to see your data, the file you are feeding to the csh script.

Comment: If you have a forward slash inside a regex bounded by forward slashes, you need to escape it (`\/`) or choose different delimiters.

Comment: Oh, I do not have that file with me.

Comment: Thanks, it worked after I escaped it as @MattJacob mentioned. "next if (!m/::RUNTIME:: SHIP end time//date:/);"".

Comment: Uhhh... that's a syntax error (and also not what I suggested). I'm tempted to flag this question as a typo, because had you attempted to run this code, Perl immediately would have alerted you to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> I am not sure if this line is right ""`next if (!m/::RUNTIME:: SHIP end time/date:/);`"" because I see in my texteditor "`date:/`" showing in a different color. So I am guessing the syntax is wrong.

Yup, you're right (as a quick test would have told you). Since you chose `/` as your delimiter, it marks the end of the pattern. What follows are the two most commonly-used solutions:

```
next if !/::RUNTIME:: SHIP end time\/date:/;   # Escape
next if !m{::RUNTIME:: SHIP end time/date:};   # Alternate delimiter.
```